# Displaying view/progress spinner/error view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I have a frame layout with 2 children. A custom view and a progress bar.
Only 1 at a time is visible. Works as I need.
I want to also add some error view which will display an error and the other components would be hidden.
Is using a FrameLayout a good idea or should I switch to RelativeLayout?

Comment: Based on that one is visible at a time, It shouldn't matter.

Comment: have you thought about AsyncTask ??

Answer (score 1):

If the layout works for you I would stick to `FrameLayout`. Since there are only 3 children (and assuming that none of them has children) the difference in performance should be really minimal (if any), but one difference I noticed digging into the source code of both `FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayout` is in the `onMeasure` method, `FrameLayout` will iterate twice all of its children, `RelativeLayout` iterates from 3 to 7 times (!)
you can check [FrameLayout onMeasure](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/widget/FrameLayout.java#FrameLayout.onMeasure%28int%2Cint%29) and [RelativeLayout onMeasure](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java#RelativeLayout.onMeasure%28int%2Cint%29) yourself